# Angular8 app http error 405 on page refresh

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, http, post

i am developing an using Angular8 and .NET Core 3.0 in Visual Studio. I have a page with a form which is working without any issues. However when i press F5 on that page i get the following error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405
>   (Method Not Allowed) [http://localhost:51871/notifications]

This is the submit function in the component class

```
  onSubmit() {

    if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    let post: NotificationsInterface = {
      email: this.registerForm.value.email,
      subject: this.registerForm.value.subject,
      text: this.registerForm.value.text,
    };

    this.http.post("Notifications", post).subscribe(result => {
      console.error("ok");

    }, error => console.error("error"));

  }
```

This is the notification class in C#

```
public class Notifications
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

This is the controller in C#

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using HomeHelper.Models;

namespace HomeHelper.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class NotificationsController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Notifications notification)
        {

            return Ok();

        }
   }
}
```

When i comment the controller part in C# the error is gone, however the data cannot be received. What is the best practice for such errors to be avoided ?
The error only occurs in the url " http://localhost:51871/notifications "
Best regards!

UPDATE: I have added the full code of the controller and the url with the specified error.

Comment: what is the url for angular app and c# app ? (generally domain point to angular app like localhost/xyz , localhost/abc , and one prefix endpoint for api like localhost/api/myApis , so we dont hit/refresh a url that contains api only angular internally point to that url , no via browser refresh and rest all other end point redirect to angular so no error should be there.

Comment: @LogicBlower Thank you for your reply ! I have updated my question with more detailed expalanation, in short the url is  " http://localhost:51871/notifications " and i have added the full controller logic. Kind regards.

Comment: your angular url is  localhost:51871/notifications  and backend Api url is too :  localhost:51871/notifications   : both are same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug this issues by creating a **get route** with same end point in your controller.

when you refresh your Angular application as you have a route  `localhost:51871/notifications` in your controller your server resolves the route and points you to the controller but as of now there is no Get method (as browser sends a get request when you refresh) so it gives you error.

I guess either to adopt to hash location strategy or try changing the angular route  or you can do is all your backend api url should work  if there is a api in the url path

like `localhost:51871/api/notifications` that will help to sort api is getting called

Comment: Hello, your solution also worked. However the answer you provided is more detailed and well explained which can help other developers understand better how controllers work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using hash location strategy.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})
```